# Slow Double for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a double loop that runs over a dataset comparing 1 row to the next on multiple matching conditions. When a condition is met, the matched pair is added to the list. The code works fine for small dataset but it quite slow for anything more than 5k rows.

I would really appreciate it if anyone has any ideas to improve the performance.

Below are the code and underlying data.

Basically I import the data from excel.

```
result = []
                                
def is_match(base_row, next_row):
    return base_row['NOTIONAL'] == next_row['NOTIONAL'] and base_row['LEG'] != next_row['LEG'] and \
    base_row['REF_RATE'] == next_row['REF_RATE'] and abs(base_row['RATE'] - next_row['RATE']) < 0.15 and \
    abs((base_row['MATURITY_DATE'] - next_row['MATURITY_DATE']).days) <= 30

df_len = len(df.index)
for base_index, base_row in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(base_index + 1, df_len):
        if is_match(base_row, df.loc[i]):
            result.append((base_index, i))
```

| BUSN_DATE | TRADE_ID | LEG | TYPE | REF_RATE | RATE | NOTIONAL | MATURITY_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/12/2020 | 12345_P | PAY | FIXED | FIXED | 1.50 | 10000000 | 31/12/2021 |
| 9/12/2020 | 12345_R | REC | FLOAT | BBSW | 1.25 | 10000000 | 31/12/2021 |
| 9/12/2020 | 12346_R | REC | FIXED | FIXED | 1.55 | 10000000 | 27/12/2021 |
| 9/12/2020 | 12346_P | PAY | FLOAT | BBSW | 1.30 | 10000000 | 27/12/2021 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'BUSN_DATE': {0: '9/12/2020', 1: '9/12/2020', 2: '9/12/2020', 3: '9/12/2020'},
 'TRADE_ID': {0: '12345_P', 1: '12345_R', 2: '12346_R', 3: '12346_P'},
 'LEG': {0: 'PAY', 1: 'REC', 2: 'REC', 3: 'PAY'},
 'TYPE': {0: 'FIXED', 1: 'FLOAT', 2: 'FIXED', 3: 'FLOAT'},
 'REF_RATE': {0: 'FIXED', 1: 'BBSW', 2: 'FIXED', 3: 'BBSW'},
 'RATE': {0: '1.50', 1: '1.25', 2: '1.55', 3: '1.30'},
 'NOTIONAL': {0: '10000000', 1: '10000000', 2: '10000000', 3: '10000000'},
 'MATURITY_DATE': {0: '31/12/2021',
  1: '31/12/2021',
  2: '27/12/2021',
  3: '27/12/2021'}})
```

Comment: How much time it takes?

Comment: In general I would advice to do something like this in a database and not in pandas.
It would be faster to do something like a subselect on indexed data for each row. This way, you do not have to go to all other rows each time.

Comment: @Suman it takes about 1 hour to run through 10k rows.

Comment: @Semmel I agree it would be much quicker to do this in database. However, we may not have this functionality until next year.

Comment: It will make it more likely someone will be able to help if you post the source dataframe in a form that people can copy/paste and work with as opposed to a screenshot (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ), as well as your expected output. That said, you can access the next row of a column by using `shift(1)`, so I think this should be something you can do in a couple of lines in pandas.

Comment: you may need to apply `df_len` time if you use `shift` to generate the next row dataframe with the condition. I think from your condition, there will be a more efficent way to do that, but you should provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'BUSN_DATE': {0: '9/12/2020', 1: '9/12/2020', 2: '9/12/2020', 3: '9/12/2020'},
 'TRADE_ID': {0: '12345_P', 1: '12345_R', 2: '12346_R', 3: '12346_P'},
 'LEG': {0: 'PAY', 1: 'REC', 2: 'REC', 3: 'PAY'},
 'TYPE': {0: 'FIXED', 1: 'FLOAT', 2: 'FIXED', 3: 'FLOAT'},
 'REF_RATE': {0: 'FIXED', 1: 'BBSW', 2: 'FIXED', 3: 'BBSW'},
 'RATE': {0: '1.50', 1: '1.25', 2: '1.55', 3: '1.30'},
 'NOTIONAL': {0: '10000000', 1: '10000000', 2: '10000000', 3: '10000000'},
 'MATURITY_DATE': {0: '31/12/2021',
  1: '31/12/2021',
  2: '27/12/2021',
  3: '27/12/2021'}})
```

Fix up datatypes:

```
df['BUSN_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BUSN_DATE'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df['MATURITY_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MATURITY_DATE'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df['RATE'] = pd.to_numeric(df['RATE'])
```

Create a longer version of the df for a test (10k records):

```
df = pd.concat([df]*2500).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This function will be used to apply your conditions to each sub-dataframe:

```
def is_match(x):
    idx = x['idx'];
    tmp = df[idx:]
    cond = ( tmp['NOTIONAL'] == x['NOTIONAL'])
    cond &= ( tmp['LEG'] != x['LEG'] )
    cond &= ( tmp['REF_RATE'] == x['REF_RATE'])
    cond &= ( abs(tmp['RATE'] - x['RATE']) < 0.15 )
    cond &= ( ( tmp['MATURITY_DATE'] - x['MATURITY_DATE']).dt.days <= 30 )
    return list(zip( (idx,)*sum(cond), tmp[cond].index.values) )
```

Make an index column, and apply that function to find the matches. It returns a column with the list of pairs for each row:

```
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'idx'})

result = df.apply(is_match, axis=1)

print(result[:5])

0    [(0, 2), (0, 6), (0, 10), (0, 14), (0, 18), (0...
1    [(1, 3), (1, 7), (1, 11), (1, 15), (1, 19), (1...
2    [(2, 4), (2, 8), (2, 12), (2, 16), (2, 20), (2...
3    [(3, 5), (3, 9), (3, 13), (3, 17), (3, 21), (3...
4    [(4, 6), (4, 10), (4, 14), (4, 18), (4, 22), (...
```

Comment: thank you for going through this. Unfortunately, this shift doesn't work well in this case. Through I'm trying to do the following: Use row 1 as base and match it with the next row on multiple conditions. if row 1 and row 2 don't match then do the same for row 3 and so on. If there is a match store it in the list as a tuple. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I understand what you want to do now. I'll edit it with something that might work for you.

Comment: I have just added the sample dataset. I hope that makes it slightly easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  Did that solve your problem in the end?

Comment: yes it absolutely did. It is far quicker than what I had before (the loop).

Answer (score 0):

create a  function `create_cross_join` to create a combinations cross join dataframe with raw df.

```
import itertools
def create_cross_join(dfn):
    dfn = dfn.reset_index()
    # create a combinations with 2 elemens
    # -> [0,1,2,3] 
    # -> [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
    df_combine_idx = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(dfn.index, 2), columns = ['a', 'b'])
    dfa = dfn.loc[df_combine_idx['a']].reset_index(drop=True)
    dfb = dfn.loc[df_combine_idx['b']].reset_index(drop=True).add_suffix('_2')
    dfab = pd.concat([dfa, dfb], axis = 1)
    return dfab

# convert float type and datetime type
df['RATE'] = df['RATE'].astype(float)
for col in ['BUSN_DATE', 'MATURITY_DATE']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# refer columns   
cols = ['NOTIONAL', 'REF_RATE', 'LEG', 'RATE', 'MATURITY_DATE']        


print(create_cross_join(df[cols]))

    |    |   index |   NOTIONAL | REF_RATE   | LEG   |   RATE | MATURITY_DATE       |   index_2 |   NOTIONAL_2 | REF_RATE_2   | LEG_2   |   RATE_2 | MATURITY_DATE_2     |
    |---:|--------:|-----------:|:-----------|:------|-------:|:--------------------|----------:|-------------:|:-------------|:--------|---------:|:--------------------|
    |  0 |       0 |   10000000 | FIXED      | PAY   |   1.5  | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 |         1 |     10000000 | BBSW         | REC     |     1.25 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 |
    |  1 |       0 |   10000000 | FIXED      | PAY   |   1.5  | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 |         2 |     10000000 | FIXED        | REC     |     1.55 | 2021-12-27 00:00:00 |
    |  2 |       0 |   10000000 | FIXED      | PAY   |   1.5  | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 |         3 |     10000000 | BBSW         | PAY     |     1.3  | 2021-12-27 00:00:00 |
    |  3 |       1 |   10000000 | BBSW       | REC   |   1.25 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 |         2 |     10000000 | FIXED        | REC     |     1.55 | 2021-12-27 00:00:00 |
    |  4 |       1 |   10000000 | BBSW       | REC   |   1.25 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 |         3 |     10000000 | BBSW         | PAY     |     1.3  | 2021-12-27 00:00:00 |
    |  5 |       2 |   10000000 | FIXED      | REC   |   1.55 | 2021-12-27 00:00:00 |         3 |     10000000 | BBSW         | PAY     |     1.3  | 2021-12-27 00:00:00 |
```

use group by 'NOTIONAL', 'REF_RATE' for the same NOTIONAL and REF_RATE, and reduce the cross join size.

```py
def main(df):
    result_list = []
    for (NOTIONAL, REF_RATE), group in df.groupby(['NOTIONAL', 'REF_RATE']):
        print(f'handle <NOTIONAL:{NOTIONAL}, REF_RATE:{REF_RATE}>')
        col_cond = ['LEG', 'RATE', 'MATURITY_DATE']
        dfm = create_cross_join(group[col_cond])
        cond = True
        cond &= dfm['LEG'] != dfm['LEG_2']
        cond &= abs(dfm['RATE'] - dfm['RATE_2']) < 0.15    
        cond &= abs((dfm['MATURITY_DATE'] - dfm['MATURITY_DATE_2']).dt.days) <= 30
        match_list = dfm.loc[cond, ['index', 'index_2']].values.tolist()
        if len(match_list) > 0:
            result_list.extend(match_list)
    return (result_list) 
result_list = main(df)
```

---

speed test:

```
data = [{'BUSN_DATE': '9/12/2020', 'TRADE_ID': '12345_P', 'LEG': 'PAY', 'TYPE': 'FIXED', 'REF_RATE': 'FIXED', 'RATE': 1.5, 'NOTIONAL': 10000000, 'MATURITY_DATE': '31/12/2021'},
        {'BUSN_DATE': '9/12/2020', 'TRADE_ID': '12345_R', 'LEG': 'REC', 'TYPE': 'FLOAT', 'REF_RATE': 'BBSW', 'RATE': 1.25, 'NOTIONAL': 10000000, 'MATURITY_DATE': '31/12/2021'},
        {'BUSN_DATE': '9/12/2020', 'TRADE_ID': '12346_R', 'LEG': 'REC', 'TYPE': 'FIXED', 'REF_RATE': 'FIXED', 'RATE': 1.55, 'NOTIONAL': 10000000, 'MATURITY_DATE': '27/12/2021'}, 
        {'BUSN_DATE': '9/12/2020', 'TRADE_ID': '12346_P', 'LEG': 'PAY', 'TYPE': 'FLOAT', 'REF_RATE': 'BBSW', 'RATE': 1.3, 'NOTIONAL': 10000000, 'MATURITY_DATE': '27/12/2021'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data*2500)

df['RATE'] = df['RATE'].astype(float)
for col in ['BUSN_DATE', 'MATURITY_DATE']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%d/%m/%Y')
    
cols = ['NOTIONAL', 'REF_RATE', 'LEG', 'RATE', 'MATURITY_DATE']    
print(df.shape)
result_list = main(df)
# 10k rows -> 46s -> 12500000
```

---

result:

```
result_list[:10]

    [[1, 3],
     [1, 7],
     [1, 11],
     [1, 15],
     [1, 19],
     [1, 23],
     [1, 27],
     [1, 31],
     [1, 35],
     [1, 39]]
```